# Error running neural net

Tags: r, neural-network

```
library(nnet)
set.seed(9850)
train1<- sample(1:155,110)
test1 <- setdiff(1:110,train1)
ideal <- class.ind(hepatitis$class)
hepatitisANN = nnet(hepatitis[train1,-20], ideal[train1,], size=10, softmax=TRUE)
j <- predict(hepatitisANN, hepatitis[test1,-20], type="class")
hepatitis[test1,]$class
table(predict(hepatitisANN, hepatitis[test1,-20], type="class"),hepatitis[test1,]$class)
confusionMatrix(hepatitis[test1,]$class, j)
```

Error:

```
Error in nnet.default(hepatitis[train1, -20], ideal[train1, ], size = 10,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
In addition: Warning message:
In nnet.default(hepatitis[train1, -20], ideal[train1, ], size = 10,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

hepatitis variable consists of the hepatitis dataset available on UCI.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is because you have character values in your data.

Try reading the hepatitis dataset with na.strings = "?". This is defined in the description of the dataset on the uci page.

```
headers <- c("Class","AGE","SEX","STEROID","ANTIVIRALS","FATIGUE","MALAISE","ANOREXIA","LIVER BIG","LIVER FIRM","SPLEEN PALPABLE","SPIDERS","ASCITES","VARICES","BILIRUBIN","ALK PHOSPHATE","SGOT","ALBUMIN","PROTIME","HISTOLOGY")
hepatitis <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/hepatitis/hepatitis.data", header = FALSE, na.strings = "?")
names(hepatitis) <- headers

library(nnet)
set.seed(9850)
train1<- sample(1:155,110)
test1 <- setdiff(1:110,train1)

ideal <- class.ind(hepatitis$Class)

# will give error due to missing values
# 1st column of hepatitis dataset is the class variable
hepatitisANN <- nnet(hepatitis[train1,-1], ideal[train1,], size=10, softmax=TRUE)
```

This code will not give your error, but it will give an error on missing values. You will need to do address those before you can continue.
Also be aware that the class variable is the first variable in the dataset straight from the UCI data repository

**Edit based on comments:**

The na.action only works if you use the formula notation of nnet.
So in your case:

```
hepatitisANN <- nnet(class.ind(Class)~., hepatitis[train1,], size=10,  softmax=TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
```

Comment: I slightly modified the dataset and class is my 20th attribute, also included na.action="na.omit" in the nnet function but still the same error shows up.

Comment: check the structure of your dataset. But in the original dataset the missing values are a question mark. If you do not take that into account, your values will be a character. Check str(hepatitis) to see if you have a character column somewhere. Because that is what this error is pointing to.

Comment: no character column is there but can you please help me regarding how do i take care of these question marks in the dataset?

Comment: See my answer, the option na.strings = "?" in the read.csv command. if you need to this can be na.strings = c("?", " ", etc etc) if there are more than one kind of missing values.

Comment: thank you, I tried implementing that and added the parameter na.action="na.omit" in the nnet function -> 
hepatitisANN = nnet(hepatitis[train1,-1], ideal[train1,], size=10, softmax=TRUE, na.action = "na.omit") but on doing this I get another error -> Error in nnet.default(cleveland[train1, -14], ideal[train1, ], size = 10,  : 
  missing values in 'x',    if you could help

Comment: Thank you so much for that. It works all fine. Thank you again, but another question, why didn't the code I wrote work?

Comment: @amankedia The na.action only works in formula mode. Because the formula notation only works on a dataframe / matrix it knows which y variables also need to be deleted. btw, if it works accept the answer, it also helps your score on SO

Comment: thank you it did work on a couple of datasets, trying on the rest